# Trying to run react app from browser using npm start but i have "airbnb" error

Tags: reactjs, npm

im trying to view my code that is running from browser using npm start. everything loads perfect but i still have this error code:

````
Failed to load config "airbnb" to extend from.
Referenced from: /Users/samiennaciri/Desktop/pg_se/.eslintrc.js```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to load config "airbnb" to extend from - gitlab ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69733256/failed-to-load-config-airbnb-to-extend-from-gitlab-ci)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the airbnb eslint configuration without having it installed. Install the package and following the instructions: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb

```bash
npm install --save-dev eslint-config-airbnb
```

Answer (score -1):

Install these packages

```
npm install -g install-peerdeps install-peerdeps --dev eslint-config-airbnb install-peerdeps --dev eslint-config-airbnb-base
```